# How can I count the number of profile views?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Here is my table structure:

```
-- users
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+
| id |  name  |       email         | password |      cookie        |
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+
| 1  | Jack   | jack0011@gmail.com  | 098u23r8 | kj3409t34034u8rf   |
| 2  | Peter  | wanter_s@gmail.com  | k0io34r4 | m32i0949y834rf34   |
| 3  | Martin | dr.mrtn@yahoo.com   | fg345t34 | rf34r89p23r49i34   |
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+

-- user_details
+---------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| user_id | age  |          about       |   birth_date   |
+---------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| 1       | 32   | NULL                 | NULL           |
| 2       | NULL | A senior developer   | 1992-02-10     |
| 3       | 18   | NULL                 | 1999-01-06     |
+---------+------+----------------------+----------------+

-- profile_views
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | user_id | viewer_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 1  | 2       | 1         |
| 2  | 1       | 2         |
| 3  | 1       | 3         |
+----+---------+-----------+
-- Unique Index: seen(user_id,viewer_id)
```

And here is my `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW `user` AS 
SELECT u.id,
       u.name,
       ud.age,
       ud.about,
       ud.birth_date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_details ON u.id = ud.user_id
```

---

**The Current Output:**

```
-- Assuming :user_id = 1
-- SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :user_id
+----+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| id |  name  | age  |          about       |   birth_date   |
+----+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| 1  | Jack   | 32   | NULL                 | NULL           |
+----+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+
```

**The Expected Output:**

```
+----+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
| id |  name  | age  |          about       |   birth_date   | profile_views |
+----+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 1  | Jack   | 32   | NULL                 | NULL           | 2             |
+----+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you have to join with profile view as well as user details like

```
SELECT distinct u.id,
       u.name,
       ud.age,
       ud.about,
       ud.birth_date
       count(pf.viewer_id)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_details ud ON u.id = ud.user_id
INNER JOIN profile_views pf ON u.id = pf.user_id
group by u.id,
           u.name,
           ud.age,
           ud.about,
           ud.birth_date
```

Comment: Are you sure about `INNER JOIN`? I guess it returns no row selected when an user doesn't have any view.

Comment: @stack try to run this query and tell me if there is any error

Comment: Also do you think is `group by` needed? Since the result always is one row.

Comment: @stack yeah we need to use group by or aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

Count user

```
CREATE VIEW `user` AS 
SELECT u.id,
   u.name,
   ud.age,
   ud.about,
   ud.birth_date,
   count(pv.user_id) AS 'Profile_View'
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_details ud ON u.id = ud.user_id
INNER JOIN profile_views pv ON u.id = pv.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

View Count thing is highly accessible thing. You should not rely on only mysql. Yes of course, you can store every records but fetching the count every time would be very costly. It is not good for highly scalable system as well. Your user base is increasing day by day. mysql will have to calculate after scanning the entire table every time.

Keep this database structure. Add one table where you will have two fields user_id, view_count.

Every time a use is viewed. Increment the view count of that user. obviously the user id is a key.

You can use Redis/Memcached for storing the view count.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Upvote. Actually in reality, I've a trigger after insert on `profile_views` table which increases the value of a record in `users` table.